# Batch insertion of related tables

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mybatis

So I decided to test batch statements. This is very simplified structure:

```
customer
  has many contracts
     has many payments
```

My implementation is based on mybatis in java, but I believe the question is more about pure sql. I want to check if every person in database is up to date. So I am checking policy one by one and I am checking if any data are missing/should be updated/should be deleted.

As I want to speedup this process I decided to

1. use batch for each person to avoid hundreds of statements
2. one transaction to each batch, whole person data or nothing

So lets start from case when we have only brand new customers.
So my code generate something like: (each domain one by one, without any order)

Batch ONE

```
insert into policy (name) values ('policyA')

insert into contract (personId, name) values (?, 'contractA')
insert into contract (personId, name) values (?, 'contractB')

insert into payment (contractId, name) values (?, 'ToContractA')
insert into payment (contractId, name) values (?, 'ToContractB')
insert into payment (contractId, name) values (?, 'ToContractA')
insert into payment (contractId, name) values (?, 'ToContractB')
```

...
Batch X

```
insert into policy (name) values ('policyX')
... same as above
```

at the begginig I found something called SCOPE_IDENTITY()
which would help me with

```
insert into policy (name) values ('policyA')
insert into contract (personId, name) values (select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'contractA') //here it is working
insert into contract (personId, name) values (select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'contractB') //here it will broke as it will return id of newly created contract instead policy
```

then I found SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘TableName’) which is almost my solution but it breaks for cases when something outside session is inserting in my database(which is possible).

So I have two question

1. how to dynamically place those ids
2. is it good approach to speedup process usings such batches(above example is very simplified I have much more complex structure)

Comment: Use parametrized prepared queries for extra performance and security (to avoid SQL injection)

Comment: like I said it is written in java, so sql injection is impossible as it is only projection of queries

Comment: Not sure why SQL injection is impossible in Java. Moreover, if you are better off using prepared queries to avoid the performance hit associated with parsing the query and generating and execution plan. You also have the option of inserting rows with no logging which will boost your performance.

Comment: You could also consider using BCP utility. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to first write this code in your application. I think you are underestimating the performance of executing SQL from your application.  Once you have a testable repeatable baseline you can attempt to make changes for performance. However, its rare that you will care as performance is almost always dictated by IO performance in these cases.

Its not really clear what you mean by batching. If you are talking about grouping sql within a single mybatis call I would say that is unecessary.

Transactions should be used carefully as it influences your error flow. You have to ask if a failure at any point during the process should rollback one of your inserts or all of your insert?  If you rollback only a single insert do you have a method to continue from where it failed?

Comment: like I wrote in the middle "one transaction to each batch, whole person data or nothing" and I am protected against failures already. The question is more about performance. Mybatis is set to batch mode, so java is just collecting queries in batch and when I am done with each person I just call flush to sent all data at once. And of course I have repeatable and testable version, but it is version with disabled batch mode, as i dont know how to write those batch statements from above, so I have only 1 version, so there is nothing to compare with.